# Can I solve a model in GEKKO with Black Box, Simulated Annealing or GA solvers?

Tags: optimization, python, penalty-method, gekko

I'm trying to use my current GEKKO model with different solvers methodologies. I don't know if I can also use global optimisation solvers as GA, Simulated Annealing o Differential Evolution. I need that, because I cannot use constraints in my model because I cannot develop my constraints with GEKKO functions (log, sqrt, etc). I'm trying to solve my model with some global optimisation package, and Scipy doesn't allow that. You cannot use integer values and it's necessary in my problem.

Does GEKKO these kind of solvers too?
How can I do Global Optimization (black box, simulated annealing,...) with integer values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gekko / APMonitor provides the following to Nonlinear Programming Solvers (APOPT, BPOPT, IPOPT, MINOS, SNOPT) in sparse form:

- Variables with default values and constraints
- Objective function
- Equations
- Evaluation of equation residuals
- Sparsity structure
- Gradients (1st derivatives)
- Gradient of the equations
- Gradient of the objective function
- Hessian of the Lagrangian (2nd derivatives)
- 2nd Derivative of the equations
- 2nd Derivative of the objective function

Once the solution is complete, results are written in results.json that is loaded back into the Python variables by GEKKO. A simulated annealing, GA, or other type of gradient-free algorithm would only need the following:

- Variables with default values and constraints
- Objective function
- Equations
- Evaluation of equation residuals

For this reason, I'd recommend that you do the calculations with Python NumPy or Math functions. Below is a Simulated Annealing example in Python.

**Objective Function Contour Plot**

[image: Objective Function]

**Objective Function and Temperature Decrease with Iterations**

[image: Iterations]

```py
## Generate a contour plot
# Import some other libraries that we'll need
# matplotlib and numpy packages must also be installed
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import math

# define objective function
def f(x):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    obj = 0.2 + x1**2 + x2**2 - 0.1*math.cos(6.0*3.1415*x1) - 0.1*math.cos(6.0*3.1415*x2)
    return obj

# Start location
x_start = [0.8, -0.5]

# Design variables at mesh points
i1 = np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, 0.01)
i2 = np.arange(-1.0, 1.0, 0.01)
x1m, x2m = np.meshgrid(i1, i2)
fm = np.zeros(x1m.shape)
for i in range(x1m.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x1m.shape[1]):
        fm[i][j] = 0.2 + x1m[i][j]**2 + x2m[i][j]**2 \
             - 0.1*math.cos(6.0*3.1415*x1m[i][j]) \
             - 0.1*math.cos(6.0*3.1415*x2m[i][j])

# Create a contour plot
plt.figure()
# Specify contour lines
#lines = range(2,52,2)
# Plot contours
CS = plt.contour(x1m, x2m, fm)#,lines)
# Label contours
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
# Add some text to the plot
plt.title('Non-Convex Function')
plt.xlabel('x1')
plt.ylabel('x2')

##################################################
# Simulated Annealing
##################################################
# Number of cycles
n = 50
# Number of trials per cycle
m = 50
# Number of accepted solutions
na = 0.0
# Probability of accepting worse solution at the start
p1 = 0.7
# Probability of accepting worse solution at the end
p50 = 0.001
# Initial temperature
t1 = -1.0/math.log(p1)
# Final temperature
t50 = -1.0/math.log(p50)
# Fractional reduction every cycle
frac = (t50/t1)**(1.0/(n-1.0))
# Initialize x
x = np.zeros((n+1,2))
x[0] = x_start
xi = np.zeros(2)
xi = x_start
na = na + 1.0
# Current best results so far
xc = np.zeros(2)
xc = x[0]
fc = f(xi)
fs = np.zeros(n+1)
fs[0] = fc
# Current temperature
t = t1
# DeltaE Average
DeltaE_avg = 0.0
for i in range(n):
    print('Cycle: ' + str(i) + ' with Temperature: ' + str(t))
    for j in range(m):
        # Generate new trial points
        xi[0] = xc[0] + random.random() - 0.5
        xi[1] = xc[1] + random.random() - 0.5
        # Clip to upper and lower bounds
        xi[0] = max(min(xi[0],1.0),-1.0)
        xi[1] = max(min(xi[1],1.0),-1.0)
        DeltaE = abs(f(xi)-fc)
        if (f(xi)>fc):
            # Initialize DeltaE_avg if a worse solution was found
            #   on the first iteration
            if (i==0 and j==0): DeltaE_avg = DeltaE
            # objective function is worse
            # generate probability of acceptance
            p = math.exp(-DeltaE/(DeltaE_avg * t))
            # determine whether to accept worse point
            if (random.random()<p):
                # accept the worse solution
                accept = True
            else:
                # don't accept the worse solution
                accept = False
        else:
            # objective function is lower, automatically accept
            accept = True
        if (accept==True):
            # update currently accepted solution
            xc[0] = xi[0]
            xc[1] = xi[1]
            fc = f(xc)
            # increment number of accepted solutions
            na = na + 1.0
            # update DeltaE_avg
            DeltaE_avg = (DeltaE_avg * (na-1.0) +  DeltaE) / na
    # Record the best x values at the end of every cycle
    x[i+1][0] = xc[0]
    x[i+1][1] = xc[1]
    fs[i+1] = fc
    # Lower the temperature for next cycle
    t = frac * t

# print solution
print('Best solution: ' + str(xc))
print('Best objective: ' + str(fc))

plt.plot(x[:,0],x[:,1],'y-o')
plt.savefig('contour.png')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot(fs,'r.-')
ax1.legend(['Objective'])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.plot(x[:,0],'b.-')
ax2.plot(x[:,1],'g--')
ax2.legend(['x1','x2'])

# Save the figure as a PNG
plt.savefig('iterations.png')

plt.show()
```

Here is additional information on [Genetic Algorithms (book chapter)](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/GeneticAlgorithms) and [Simulated Annealing](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/SimulatedAnnealing). If you need integer variables then you could round off candidate solutions or use some other method to ensure that there is a sufficient perturbation from the prior solution. There is also a [SciPy simulated annealing solver](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.anneal.html) although I haven't used it.